# what's is the good frequency for switching mode power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

What’s the good frequency of switching mode power supply to have good efficiency?

Comment: If efficiency is your only goal, the lower the better.  if size mass and price are also issues, you'll have to compromise.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the power level and how good is good. The power grid runs on 50/60 Hz although not switched for a reason.

GW HVDC substations switches at about 50-2000 Hz. 
MW traction converters for trains around 1 kHz. 
Multi kW-power supplies for inductrial applications around 5-10 kHz. 
kW level high end amplifiers and welding equipment at about 50-100 kHz. 
100 W laptop chargers and the like at about 60-200 kHz. 
Small 10 W cell phone chargers at ~500 kHz. 
Integrated single-W converters inside computers and simular in the MHz region.